# Getting multiple property and value using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a pair of **Property** and **Value** in a url of odata that is inside the **$filter** so i have this URL

> /odata/TopSellingItem?$expand=Item,Item($select=Name),Branch,Branch($select=Name,$filter=A
>   ne
>   'B')&$filter=Year+eq+2015+and+Month+eq+'January'&$select=Year,Month,Value

and i want to get the result

- A ne 'B'
- Year+eq+2015
- Month+eq+'January'

i tried

```
(?<=\$filter=)(.*?)(?=\&|\))
```

but i only captured

- A ne 'B'
- Year+eq+2015+and+Month+eq+'January'

is there something like reevaluating the result of captured groups to find another set of pattern or any other best way to achive my goal

Thanks in advance

I prepared an online tester

https://regex101.com/r/jO6nU5/1

Comment: Your string has "ne" not "new"...

Comment: Why not just take the 2 results that you get and then process them in a second step (like split them on `+and+` or whatever your exact requirements are). Or is there any reason why it has to be done with a single regular expression?

Comment: Yes i can do that but on my requirements, it requires 1 line of regex only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework or brain teaser for an interview, but I'll bite ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jO6nU5/2)):

```
\$filter=(.+?)(?:&|\)|(\+and\+))(?(2)([^&)]+))
```

You then extract group 1 and 3. Explanation:

```
\$filter=(.+?)      -- match any character after `$filter` and put them into capture group 1
(?:&|\)|(\+and\+))  -- stop when you encounter `&`, `)` or `+and+`
                    -- if you stop at `+and+`, put that into capture group 2
(?(2)([^&)]+))      -- if capture group 2 participated in the match,
                    -- continue capturing until `&` or `)`
```

`(?(condition)then|else)` is a conditional:

- The condition can be a lookahead `(?(?=pattern)then|else)`, a lookbehind, or their negative variants.
- It can also be a check that group `n` participated in the match `(?(n)then|else)`, which is what we used. The `else` part is not needed here.

---

**Disclaimer:** this has a limitation of matching only 1 `+and+`. For example, given this string:

```
$filter=abc+and+213+and+1234

Group 1 = abc
Group 2 = +and+
Group 3 = 213+and+1234
```

I welcome all efforts to improve it.

Comment: hey, its working.. thanks a lot sir. actually, i am creating an extension for Odata that i dont need to put the Enum namespace to value in filter query if there is a property that is an Enum.. ;)